# How to get SSID of the wifi access point from supplicant state change broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have register for Broadcast receiver `SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` where i am watching for wifi supplicant state change.

When wifi supplication state is connected or disconnected then i want to display Toast message to the user saying you are connected/disconnected from this SSID.

I don't know from the `SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast receiver how can we retrieve the SSID for which this events has occurred or broadcast has been received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use WifiManager to obtain SSID.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String ssid = wm.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
```

Also you need to save SSID into your preferences to display it when you recieve "disconnection" broadcast. Storing SSID in a variable will be unsafe, because it can be deleted by garbage collector at any time.

Comment: Would it not only be deleted by the garbage collector when it is no longer accessible by the running code in which case it is no longer needed anyway?

Comment: This depends on how you registered your broadcast receiver. If you registered it in manifest, receiver will work also when gc freed memory. In this case you'll need to use preferences. If you register receiver in runtime, you can store SSID in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

try using `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`

> Broadcast intent action indicating that the state of Wi-Fi connectivity has changed. One extra provides the new state in the form of a NetworkInfo object. If the new state is CONNECTED, additional extras may provide the BSSID and WifiInfo of the access point. as a String.

Comment: But in case if wifi is disconnected i need to display message saying wifi 'SSID' is disconnected. this broadcast only provide information related to wifi access point in case of connected state only. I need ssid in both connected and disconnected state.